# Using Kendo UI MVC DropDownListFor, how do i pass the selected text along to the controller during the submit form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Im using Ajax.BeginForm and I need to pass the selected text to the controller on the submit.  Right now it is passing the Value(id) but I need the Text.  Any ideas?

```
@using (Ajax.BeginFrom("Index", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" }))
{
   <fieldset>
   <ol>
      <li>
         @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Office)
            .Name("officeDropDownList")
            .DataValueField("Value")
            .DataTextField("Text")
            .DataSource(source => 
            {
               source.Read(read =>
                 {
                    read.Action("GetOffices", "Home");
                 });
            })
         )
     </li>
  </ol>
  </fieldset>


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value text of a dropdown:

```
$("#ddl").data("kendoDropDownList").text();
```

****Edit****

In order to return this data to the Controller I believe you need to change the `.Name` of the ddl to match the ViewModel property. So in your case change to `.Name("Office")`.

Comment: How do i return that to the controller?

Comment: I didn't see that you added example code, I'll adjust my answer.